# How to Bind column of jtable depend upon value of previous column in java jtable

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jtable

I have jtable with five column . There are two column which are dynamically binded from database in combo boxes. The selected value of one combo will effect the value of other. The basic of my problem is

Column 1 (combo box) user choose one of them
Column 2 (show result depending upon column 1 and user choose one of column2 options
Column 3  show results depend upon column 2

I tried using column cell editor . But Problem with method is if column is selected then all result will be shown in all rows .
I want to differ  result for different rows and column...

```
int col = jTblItemInfo.getSelectedColumn();
    int row = jTblItemInfo.getSelectedRow();
    if (col == 2) {
        TableColumn colum = jTblItemInfo.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        JComboBox batch_box = new JComboBox();
        String item_name = jTblItemInfo.getModel().getValueAt(row, col - 1).toString();
        int group_id = 0;
        if (item_name == null || item_name.equals("")) {
        } else {

            int item_id = new com.inventorymgmt.dao.ItemInfoDAO().getItemIdByName(item_name);
            group_id = new com.inventorymgmt.dao.ItemInfoDAO().getGroupIDByItemID(item_id);

            for (String result : new com.inventorymgmt.dao.BatchPriceDAO().getBatchNO(item_id)) {
                batch_box.addItem(result);
            }
            colum.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(batch_box));
        }
        if (!(group_id <= 0)) {

            jTblItemInfo.setValueAt(new com.inventorymgmt.dao.ItemGroupDAO().getItemGroupNameById(group_id), row, 6);
        }
        DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer();
        cellRenderer.setToolTipText("Choose Batch No");
        colum.setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);

    } else if (col == 4) {
        System.out.println("i n column 4");
        String item_name = jTblItemInfo.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
        String batch_no = jTblItemInfo.getModel().getValueAt(row, col - 1).toString();
        int item_id = new com.inventorymgmt.dao.ItemInfoDAO().getItemIdByName(item_name);
        if (item_name == null || batch_no == null) {
        } else {
            String[] str = //code to a
            // String price_str = str[0] + "";
            jTblItemInfo.setValueAt(str[0], row, col);//price
            jTblItemInfo.setValueAt(str[1], row, 5);//expiry date
        }
    }
```

Comment: sounds like something wrong in the code you are not showing ;-) Consider showing a SSCCE that demonstrates what you are after and how it goes wrong.

Comment: I written this code in KeyRealeased Event